# Orbot on iPhone: can't connect, possible to use WiFi?

Tags: orbot, ios

Orbot (1.6.0 Build 33 iOS) connected once after installation a few days ago, and hasn't been able to since. Multiple connection retries fail.  When attempting to connect, WiFi is dropped and connection attempts are made over a flaky 1 bar LTE connection which fails. Is there a way to configure Orbit use my home WiFi instead of LTE?

Answer (score 1):

This problem resolved itself. After a week of not working, no Tor connection, Orbit was able to connect. The iPhone WiFi icon dropped during the connection establishment and reappeared after the connection was made.